# Why is UILabel not wrapping text inspite of taking multiple lines when added programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Here is my code. `self` is a `UITableViewCell`.

```
    self.contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8.0, left: 8.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 8.0)
    self.contentView.layoutMarginsDidChange()
    self.titleView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.titleView.text = story.title
    self.titleView.font = UIFont(name: "Times-Roman", size: 15.0)
    self.titleView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    self.titleView.numberOfLines = 3
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.titleView)
    self.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.titleView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    self.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.titleView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    self.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: self.titleView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    self.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: self.titleView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    self.contentView.updateConstraints()
    self.setNeedsLayout()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

The output is that the long title takes 3 lines but the text only appears in single line and the rest two are blank. I have not specified any other height or width constraint. Will setting preferredMaxLayoutWidth help here? If yes then I want it to be automatic as I am targeting 8.0+. Am I missing to set some property of UILabel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an UITableViewCell that has a UILabel that has a dynamic height, you have to make both UILabel and the cell height dynamic.

You are on the right track with the label, but trying a bit too much.

The following minimal code works for me, though I usually set part of the stuff (constraints, number of lines) in Interface Builder

**First the label configuration**

In your UITableViewCell, in `awakeFromNib` or one of the `inits` if you are not using xibs:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Note: don't touch contentView's autoresizing masks
    self.label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.label.numberOfLines = 0 // 0 means number of lines is based on the text 

    self.contentView.addSubview(self.label)

    // Simple helper function
    func marginConstraint(a1: NSLayoutAttribute, a2: NSLayoutAttribute) {
        self.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.label, attribute: a1, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: a2, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    }
    marginConstraint(.Leading, .LeadingMargin)
    marginConstraint(.Top, .TopMargin)
    marginConstraint(.Trailing, .TrailingMargin)
    marginConstraint(.Bottom, .BottomMargin)
}
```

**Next the UITableViewCell height**

In your UITableViewController, set `rowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

If you have non-uniform cells, with some of them using fixed height, use 
`tableView(tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)` to return fixed heights to those that do not have dynamic height.

Comment: This solved my problem: // Note: don't touch contentView's autoresizing masks
    self.label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

Comment: Cool, glad that it helped you. Table views with dynamic heights can be finicky, I've spent countless hours debugging weird problems.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related with your last 2 lines of code, where you set some autolayout constraints:

```
self.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: self.titleView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
self.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: self.titleView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
```

The first autolayout constraint is saying that `self.contentview`'s trailing margin is greater or equal to `self.titleView`'s trailing.

Try something like this instead:

```
self.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.titleView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
self.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.titleView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
```

EDIT: I still think you should replace the last two constraints with the ones i provide in this answer because it is more readable that you are applying the constraints to `titleView` and attaching it to the trailing and bottom of the `contentView` just like you did in the first two constraints, but I've also found out that something else was missing.

Do this before adding any constraints:

```
self.titleView.removeConstraints(self.titleView.constraints())
self.contentView.removeConstraints(self.contentView.constraints())
```

If you don't do this, since your view seemed to be created through IB, you get auto layout constraints automatically, and then the constraints conflict between each other, getting this on the console:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>
> Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
>   (
>       "<**NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint**:0x7fd47878ef90 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(8)-UILabel:0x7fd47878c260'dsfsdf sdf sdf sdf dsf sd...'   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fd478783350 )>",
>       "",
>       "",
>       ""
>   )

Comment: Still it's not working. The issue seems to be with the label itself. The UILabel is taking multiple lines in layout but it's not showing text in all the lines. For short titles it spans in one line. For long ones it takes 2-3 lines but the second and third line always remain empty. Am I am forgetting to set some property on the label.